# Solving a differential equation with small angle approximation $\sin \theta \approx \theta$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> We want to solve $m(t)\theta''+k\theta'+\frac{m(t)g}{l}\sin(\theta)=0$. Notice that under an additional condition on $\theta$ we can transform this non-linear DE in: $m(t)\theta''+k\theta'+\frac{m(t)g}{l}\theta=0$. What is this condition?

All I can think of is $\sin(\theta)=\theta \iff \theta=0$, which makes little sense. Could anyone give me a hint how to see that we can replace $\sin(\theta)$ by $\theta$?

Comment: Note that $\sin(t)=t-t^{3}/3!+t^{5}/5!+...$ (i.e.  Taylor expansion near zero)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a "small angle approximation."

Provided that $\theta$ is small, we can say that $\sin \theta \approx \theta$.

Presumably you are modelling the movement of a pendulum - it is reasonable in such situations to have a small angle.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin(\theta)\approx\theta\left(1-\frac{\theta^2}6\right).$$

Then $\theta\ll\sqrt6$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make an approximation you can use away from $\theta\approx0$ then use the following :

$$sinx = sin((x-X_0)+X_0) = sin(x-X_0)cosX_0-sinX_0cos(x-X_0)$$

Both $sinx$ and $cosx$ have small angle approximations :

$$sinx \approx x$$
$$cosx \approx 1-\frac{x^2}{2}=\left(1-\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\approx 1-\frac{x}{{\sqrt{2}}}$$

Note : you can make other different linear approximations for these functions depending on how you want those approximations to perform.  These are just one such approximation.

So two approximately linear expressions we can use in the expansion about $X_0$ above.

And our approximation about X_0 for sin() becomes :

$$sin(x) \approx (x-X_0)cos X_0-sin X_0 \left(1-\frac{x-X_0}{2}\right)$$

Using the coordinate transform $x=X_0+s$ we can get :

$$sin(X_0+s) \approx s \, \left(cos X_0 + \frac{sin X_0}{2} \right) - sin X_0$$

And remember to transform the \theta in your DE although in this case $\theta'=s'$ and $\theta''=s''$

And we get a simpler DE for small values of $\theta-X_0$ around :

$$m(t)\, s''+ks'+\frac{m(t)g}{l}\left(\,s \, \left(cos X_0 + \frac{sin X_0}{2} \right) - sin X_0\right) = 0$$

Which I leave as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

A damped non-linear pendulum can be linearized by the approximation you suggested. The solution of non-linear pendulum is in terms of elliptic functions whereas the solution with this approximation becomes harmonic. The error for $\theta_{max} < 30^0  $ is quite low.